The cable connected to the second ONLY works if the cable from the first is connected
I'm using fiber optics for intranet, but there's one thing I don't understand yet... I tested it on a network card with two interfaces, but the cable connected to the second ONLY works if the cable from the first is connected.
The interface is UP, but it doesn't find anything out and when trying to ping it it indicates "Destination Host Unreachable for 10.10.100.12" (ip of the other interface)


root@pve-ippri-12:~# sudo ethtool ens6f1
Settings for ens6f1:
        Supported ports: [ TP    FIBRE ]
        Supported link modes:   10000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: No
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 10000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Auto-negotiation: off
        Port: FIBRE
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Supports Wake-on: g
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000000 (0)
                              
        Link detected: yes
root@pve-ippri-12:~# sudo ethtool ens6f0
Settings for ens6f0:
        Supported ports: [ TP    FIBRE ]
        Supported link modes:   10000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: No
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 10000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Auto-negotiation: off
        Port: FIBRE
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Supports Wake-on: g
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000000 (0)

*-network:0               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: cLOM8214 1/10GbE Controller
       vendor: QLogic Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
       logical name: ens6f0
       version: 54
       serial: a0:1d:48:98:3e:e0
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capacity: 10Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msix pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp fibre 10000bt-fd
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=qlcnic driverversion=5.3.66 duplex=full firmware=4.14.26 ip=10.10.100.12 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=fibre speed=10Gbit/s
       resources: irq:16 memory:92e00000-92ffffff memory:93010000-9301ffff memory:93040000-9307ffff
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: cLOM8214 1/10GbE Controller
       vendor: QLogic Corp.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.1
       logical name: ens6f1
       version: 54
       serial: a0:1d:48:98:3e:e4
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capacity: 10Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msix pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp fibre 10000bt-fd
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=qlcnic driverversion=5.3.66 duplex=full firmware=4.14.26 ip=10.10.100.22 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=fibre speed=10Gbit/s
       resources: irq:16 memory:92c00000-92dfffff memory:93000000-9300ffff memory:93080000-930bffff


Don't post pictures of text. They're unscrollable, can't be Copy/Pasted as part of an Answer, and aren't the Good Way of adding text to your Question.  See https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Look at the network logs with the terminal command: sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager.  Also do: service NetworkManager status and service --status-all. Also, inspect your Packet Routing tables with ip route show before, during, and after your plugging.
